# Rock,paper, scissor python

Tags: python-3.x

Im learning python and coding a rock, paper, and scissor game. I'm able to run the program but each time the program goes through the nested if,elif,else statement, the output continues to be  the outer *else* statement no matter what the value of  *humplayer* variable is. Any help?

Thank you!

```
    import random
def main():
    playerName=introduction() 
    humplayer=hum_player()
    compchoice=com_player()
    tieScore = 0
    humScore=0
    comScore=0
    humplayer=input("Enter your move (0 for Rock, 1 for Paper, and 2 for Scissors): ")
    while humplayer != -1:
        compchoice=com_player()
        result= evaluate_Game(humplayer,compchoice,playerName)
        if result==0:
            print("It's a tie!")
            tieScore+=1
        elif result==1:
            comScore+=1
        else:
            humScore+=1
        humplayer=input("Enter your move (0 for Rock, 1 for Paper, and 2 for Scissors): ") 
    print(statistics(playerName,humScore,comScore,tieScore))



def introduction():
    print("Welcome to the game of Rock, Paper, Scissors. You will be playing against the computer.")
    name= input("What is your name? ")
    print("Here are the rules", name+":")
    print(" If a player chooses Rock and the other chooses Scissors, Rock wins.")
    print(" If a player chooses Scissors and the other chooses Paper, Scissors wins.")
    print(" If a player chooses Paper and the other chooses Rock, Paper wins.")
    print(" If both players make the same choice, it's a tie.")
    print(" Enter -1 to quit the game ")
    return name

def hum_player():
          choice = int(input("Enter your move (0 for Rock, 1 for Paper, and 2 for Scissors): "))
          return choice

def com_player():
          random_Num = random.randint(0,2)
          return(random_Num)




def evaluate_Game(humplayer,compchoice,playerName):
    a = "Rock"
    b="Paper"
    c="Scissors"
    if humplayer==0:
       if compchoice==0:
           return 0
       elif compchoice==1:
           print(playerName, "plays ",a," computer plays",b)
           print("Paper covers Rock, Computer wins!")
           return 1
       else:
           print(playerName, "plays",a,"computer plays", c)
           print("Rock crushes Scissors ,", playerName," wins!")
           return 2
    elif humplayer==1:
       if compchoice==0:
           print(name,"plays",b," computer plays", a)
           print("Paper covers Rock.", playerName,"wins!")
           return 2
       elif compchoice==1:
           print(playerName,"plays", b," computer plays" , b)
           print("It's a tie!")
           return 0
       else:
           print(playerName, "plays", b,"computer plays", c)
           print("Scissors cuts Paper. Computer wins!")
           return 1
    else:
        if compchoice==0:
           print(playerName, "plays", c," computer plays", a)
           print("Rock breaks Scissors. Computer wins!")
           return 1 
        elif compchoice==1:
           print(playerName, "plays", c, " computer plays", b)
           print("Scissors cuts Paper." , playerName, "wins!")
           return 2
        else:
            print(playerName, "plays", c," computer plays", c)
            print("It's a tie!")
            return 0

def statistics(playerName,humScore,tieScore,comScore):
    print("There were", tieScore+comScore+humscore, "games:", playerName, "won", humScore, "games, the computer won", comScore, "games and there were", tieScore, "ties.")

main()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you re-ask for input from the human, you aren't casting it to an `int`. Rather than rewriting this line:

```
humplayer=input("Enter your move (0 for Rock, 1 for Paper, and 2 for Scissors): ")
```

why don
't you use the function you wrote and do,

```
humplayer = hum_player()
```

Although you properly cast to an `int` in your `hum_player()` function, you don't in all the other places where you requery. You may as well re-use this function. That is the reason why we write separate functions in the first place (so we don't have to repeat code that we've already written).

And a second thing that is a bit wrong is the way that you are using your `statistics()` method.

```
def statistics(playerName,humScore,tieScore,comScore):
    print("There were", tieScore+comScore+humscore, "games:", playerName, "won", humScore, "games, the computer won", comScore, "games and there were", tieScore, "ties.")
```

As written, this is actually ok. The problem is that you are calling it with

```
'print(statistics(...))`
```

The actual `statistics` method returns `None` so this print statement, is going to print `None` (although the actual function call will still print to console). The better way to do is to either just call the method:

```
statistics(...)
```

without a print statement, or change you're statistics method to return a string rather than print it.

```
def statistics(playerName,humScore,tieScore,comScore):
    return ("There were", tieScore+comScore+humscore, "games:", playerName, "won", humScore, "games, the computer won", comScore, "games and there were", tieScore, "ties.")
```

Comment: Thank! I realized that i didnt include int() with my input after posting this question but the problem with the  statistics method was new to me!